# Axios Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded when there are a lot of connections (but api answers really fast)

Tags: node.js, docker, axios, timeout, limit

I have a docker image with a nodejs frontend-app that requests some data from api with Axios.

On a server I have multiple instances of this docker image. When the count of instances became greater than 30, I'm starting getting errors like this on some container:

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded
     at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
     at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:369:16)
     at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:164:12)
     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

But at the same time when I'm trying to get data from api with wget on that server it works fine. And getting data in browser also works fine.

It looks like nodejs has some limits for outcome connections and I'm reaching it. And this limits works between docker containers, IDK how. But I can't find a way to increase it neither to debug it.

Comment: do you reach socket limit ? cat /proc/net/sockstat . or do you only load test your app and become stressed that some connections fail ? (its normal)

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO I don't know how to understand it. cat /proc/net/sockstat:
sockets: used 2121
TCP: inuse 966 orphan 3 tw 704 alloc 1050 mem 822
UDP: inuse 47 mem 48
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0

Comment: But it's definitely not about load for api - api answers really fast (about 100ms)

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO how cat I get if socket limit is reached?

Comment: usually max opened socket is arround 30K. after that i got errors on opening new socket. in your example its 2121.